# Can we change the padding property of pack layout with a transition?

Tags: layout, d3.js

At first I set padding value of my pack layout to -15. I want to change it to 0 by a transition. I could not find any info on this issue. Does anybody know if it can be done or not? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

The layouts in D3 compute the positions of the elements of the visualisation. If you change the parameters of the layout (such as the padding), those positions will be different. You would have to run the layout twice for this. The steps are as follows.

- Run the layout with the original padding.
- Draw the elements. Up to here, it should be exactly what you're doing already.
- Now run the layout again, with the new padding.
- Pass the new layout data to your `.data()` selector, as you've done before with the initial data.
- Now update the positions of the elements according to the new data. This is again very similar to what you've done before, except that you're operating on the update and not on the enter selection. You can add a transition to this update by using `.transition()`.